# What is the minimum number of spheres required to create a larger approximately sphere-like structure having symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, spheres

Suppose you are asked to create a larger sphere using smaller spheres. You can create only something that can be just contained inside a large sphere. If the smaller spheres are closely packed and stacked as layers above and below a central layer, such that it has a plane of symmetry, what is the minimum number of smaller spheres required? Has 'pi' any role in it?

If the diameter of the central layer is 7 spheres (22/7 represents the whole number fraction for 'pi' correct to 2 digits), will that represent the above structure having minimum number of spheres?

Comment: This is far too undefined to answer.  How do you create a larger sphere from smaller spheres?  What is a nearly spherical structure?  How near is acceptable?  Presumably you are arranging small spheres  to try to fill a larger sphere.  Do they have to touch?  What is perfect symmetry?  Vote to close as needing definiton.

Comment: This feels like the embryonic beginning of (possibly several related) interesting questions, but as it's phrased right now, it's too open-ended.

Comment: Perhaps ask the analogous question down a dimension in the plane where it might be easier to specify exactly what you're asking: some kind of packing/covering question with disks that combine to approximate a larger disk.

Comment: It seems that you are asking about the minimum number of spheres required to create a larger sphere that is nearly spherical and has minimal deformity, rather than perfect symmetry? Is this correct?

Comment: I have edited the question. I think it is clear now. What I wanted to know is whether someone has earlier considered such a question and arrived at an answer so that I can use it as an argument for explaining the formation of electron and neutron from smaller spherical particles.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum number of spheres required to create a larger sphere with perfect symmetry is twelve. This is known as the "Close Packing of Spheres" problem, and it has been mathematically proven that a three-dimensional arrangement of equal spheres can only achieve perfect symmetry with 12 spheres arranged around a central sphere. (see https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Circle_packing)

This arrangement is known as a face-centered cubic (FCC) lattice, and it is the most efficient way to pack spheres in three dimensions, as it provides the highest packing density.

The number "pi" ($\pi$) does play a role in the calculation of the sphere's volume, as the formula for the volume of a sphere is $V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$, where $r$ is the radius of the sphere. However, it does not play a direct role in the calculation of the number of spheres required for close packing, which is determined purely by geometrical considerations.

Comment: Note that the "larger sphere with perfect symmetry" is not a sphere and does not have rotational symmetry possessed by any sphere. I am not sure what "perfect symmetry" means. Also, packing problems look for ways to fill as many non-overlapping shapes as possible into a unit area or volume, not to obtain the most symmetric or spherical compound shape.